# Is it possible to bind gestures to my Mac's keyboard when using the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, testing

I wanted to code certain functions to run when the app receives a certain gesture. Doing these gestures on the simulator feels very slow. I was wondering if there was a way to either

1. Bind gestures such as "swipe left", "swipe right", etc. to the arrow keys

or

2. Have some code somewhere that can read what I input into the debugger so I can hardcode the functions to run when the debugger receives a certain command

The app is an iOS app and NOT a Mac app or console application